# Grouping Media Queries in Stylus

Tags: css, media-queries, stylus

Handling media queries with preprocessors is very cool, but I didn't found a way to group same rules to avoid repeated media queries rules like:

**Example 1**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div1 {
    background-color: #0c0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div2 {
    background-color: #00c;
  }
}
```

I to want to group the **same rules into a single one** like:

**Example 2**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  .div1 {
    background-color: #0c0;
  }
  .div2 {
    background-color: #00c;
  }
}
```

**MY STYLUS CODE**

This is how I am handling the media queries in Stylus:

```
media_queries = {
  mobile  : "only screen and (max-width: 600px)",
  tablet  : "only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px)",
  desktop : "only screen and (min-width: 801px)"
}
```

**And I have a function to call the media sizes:**

```
for_breakpoint(breakpoints)
  conditions = ()
  for breakpoint in breakpoints
    push(conditions, media_queries[breakpoint])
  conditions = join(", ", conditions)
  @media conditions
    {block}
```

After that, I call it inside the rules I want to have a specific media query:

```
+for_breakpoint(mobile)
  .div1
    background-color red
```

But the problem is that i ends having a tons of repeated media queries like the ones on **example 1**. Is there a way to group them like the **example 2**?

Comment: I tried to do the same some time ago, I couldn't do it. Finally I used postcss to group the mediaqueries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use plugin [groupCssMediaQueries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-group-css-media-queries):

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(groupCssMediaQueries())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
})
```